Showing if there exists unique $b$ solution for linear transformation, then it's invertible
Let $A,m\times n$ matrix and $T:F^n\to F^m$ be a linear transformation. $T(x) = Ax$
Suppose there exists $b∈F^m$ s.t there's unique vector $v$ s.t $T(v) = b$
prove $T$ is invertible.
Now basically I shown that it's injective(the easy part)
how to show that $n=m$?
I know based on rank rule that if $n>m$ then there isn't unique solution to $Ax=0$. So it ends the proof.
But I wanted to know if there is a way showing it only using linear transformations? showing somehow it must be surjective?
Thanks in advanced.

Can you show your proof that $T$ is injective?

@K.Jiang yes, suppose there is x!=0, s.t T(x)=0
but T(v) = b so from linearity of T, T(v) + T(x) = b + 0 -> T(v+x) = b, but since it's unique v+x = v -> x = 0 contradiction, thus x=0 and ker(T) = {0} so injective

You cannot prove it, since it is false. If $n=1$, $m=2$, and $T(x)=(x,0)$ (that is, if $A=[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\end{smallmatrix}]$), then there is only one element of $F$ (the field that you are working with) such that $T(x)=(1,0)$ (namely, $x=1$). However, $T$ is not surjective, and therefore $T$ is not invertible.

i must be confusing with something, i wanted to prove the following theorem for linear transformations: A is invertible iff there exists b s.t Ax=b has unique solution.

That's true for square matrices, but not in general (as my example shows).

Oh, what a newbie mistake i made, thank you very much for the clarification :)
